# Golang: Counting Inversions Sorting issue

Tags: recursion, go

I have recently started experimenting with Golang. I'm trying to write a program which counts the number of inversions with a given slice, but I have ran into an issue.

I'm trying to sort the slice using code based off MergeSort, but my code does not seem to sort the slice properly. I'm assuming that the final slice has to be sorted for the inversion count to work correctly, but I don't know how to do this. Can I get some help on this issue?

```
func InversionCount(a []int) int {
    if len(a) <= 1 {
        return 0
    }
    mid := len(a) / 2
    left := a[:mid]
    right := a[mid:]
    leftCount := InversionCount(left)
    rightCount := InversionCount(right)

    res := make([]int, 0, len(right)+len(left)) //temp slice to hold the sorted left side and right side

    iCount := mergeCount(left, right, &res)

    a = res        //Copies the result back into the original slice
    fmt.Println(a) //Why hasn't "a" been sorted?
    return iCount + leftCount + rightCount
}

func mergeCount(left, right []int, res *[]int) int {
    count := 0

    for len(left) > 0 || len(right) > 0 {
        if len(left) == 0 {
            *res = append(*res, right...)
            break
        }
        if len(right) == 0 {
            *res = append(*res, left...)
            break
        }
        if left[0] <= right[0] {
            *res = append(*res, left[0])
            left = left[1:]
        } else { //Inversion has been found
            count += 1
            *res = append(*res, right[0])
            right = right[1:]
        }
    }

    return count
}

func main() {
    s := []int{4, 3, 2, 1}
    fmt.Print(InversionCount(s))
}
```

Here is a link to my code: http://play.golang.org/p/QSJyg_qadD

Comment: Why are you assuming you need to sort the array to count the inversions?  I think you may be confused about what "counting inversions" means, this link hopefully helps clarify: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/.

Comment: Shouldn't you count the inversion as you are sorting? It seems that's what the picture in the link is showing because it shows a sorted array in the end. I know there a problems with the way I'm counting the inversions right now, but I want to get the sorting portion to work first.

Comment: I see, you're trying to apply "Method 2" listed there, instead of the simpler "Method 1" which doesn't require sorting.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the line

```
count += 1
```

with

```
count += len(left)
```

The point is that at any point in `mergeCount` where `left[0] > right[0]`, then since `left` is already sorted, **all** the remaining things in `left` are inverted relative to `right[0]`.  If you do this, you get the correct count.

The fact that your sort isn't working is a different problem.  If you're interested in fixing that, I'd recommend taking out all the count logic and just trying to fix the sort.  If you're still stuck, it probably deserves its own question.

One problem is that `InversionCount(arr)` doesn't result in `arr` being sorted, so

```
a = res        //Copies the result back into the original slice
fmt.Println(a) //Why hasn't "a" been sorted?
```

this isn't what you're wanting it to be, because earlier when you apply `mergeCount` to `left` and `right`, those subarrays `left` and `right` weren't sorted by `InversionCount`.  A simpler example of this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Foo(a []int) {
    a = []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
}

func main() {
    a := []int{4, 3, 2, 1}
    Foo(a)
    fmt.Println(a) // [4, 3, 2, 1]
}
```